# How to add embedded mounting hole screw for the NVMe ssd in a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout, kicad, ssd

I am designing a PCB for CM4 where an NVMe SSD M.2 2280 will be used. I need to add the screw terminal/mounting hole fused into the PCB (ref the image: https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/blog_InstallingMP500-Content-3.jpg I am referring that 42, 60, 80 and 110. In our case it is 80, however, all the 42, 60, 80 and 110 are the same just the position varies depending on the SSD variant). How to add that in KiCAD? Please guide me on this along with the part number for the same if any.

Comment: Why not ask your PCB fab shop can supply them and how to specify it

Answer (score 3):

You can use standoffs, the easiest kind would be classified as SMT (they do go through the board but the "through hole" kind screws in the other side vs. soldering in).

You can find them on Mouser or Digikey, you just need one for a M2 screw (the screw is M2x3) in the height required by your connector. Wurth makes some nice ones in that range. The datasheet will show you the footprint, they can be soldered my machine too (if that's your assembly plan).

Edit: as Hearth pointed out, these are actually press fit broaching nuts with a threaded standoff, not a SMT standoff. Edited my answer to clarify that SMT standoffs are an easy option, not the exact match. The exact match is probably something more like this: http://www.npfasteners.com/broaching/cbn.htm

Comment: I don't think that counts as SMT... it's press-fit through hole, no?

Comment: @Hearth you're right, I wasn't clear about SMT standoffs just being an option and not a direct match. I edited to clarify that